# how to set datatype in cusome binder in action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, binding

I have a class like below , it is a custome binder just for DateTime in mvc :

```
public class PersianDateModelBinder : IModelBinder
{

    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {...}
}
```

I want set this in action like this :

```
    public ActionResult Register([ModelBinder(typeof(PersianDateModelBinder))]  User user)
    {...}
```

how can I set DateType here ? for example I want set DateTime in Above Code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would advice you to implement custom model binder that derives from DefaultModelBinder base class and not from IModelBinder interface. This way you will have to override only methods that you need and not implementing the whole interface.

As for your question, if I understand you correct you want to bind DateTime property of User class using some custom logic. I that is your intention than this should help:

You need to override `GetPropertyValue` method of your custom model binder

```
protected override object GetPropertyValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext, 
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, 
        IModelBinder propertyBinder){
     if (propertyDescriptor.PropertyType== typeof(DateTime))
     {
        //your logic here
     }

}
```

if your model can have both properties that should use default date time binding and your custom one you can create custom attribute to mark the properties that should be using custom binding

```
[AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class PersianDateAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

and then to check in model binder that this attribute is present:

```
if (propertyDescriptor.PropertyType== typeof(DateTime) && propertyDescriptor.Attributes.OfType<PersianDateAttribute >().Any())
{
    //your logic here
}
else
{
    return base.GetPropertyValue(bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, propertyBinder);
}
```

Once your model binder is implemented, you can either use it as you did:

```
public ActionResult Register([ModelBinder(typeof(PersianDateModelBinder))]  User user)
```

or register it globally in `Application_Start` method:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new PersianDateModelBinder();
```

Comment: I had written this before, but I mean how do action, I append DateTime type to ModelBinding?

Comment: I don't understand your question... what does it mean "append DateTime type to ModelBinding"

Comment: Are you talking about registration of model binder for DateTime type? If so :  `ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(DateTime)] =  new PersianDateModelBinder() ;`

Comment: "Are you talking about registration of model binder for DateTime type?" Yes. Of course in action not in Application_Start method